# sql join query date format

Tags: sql, join, grafana

I'm trying to make nice table view (in grafana) of my trading profits where I group my trades by date.

```
SELECT
close_date AS "Date",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND c2.close_date = close_date) AS Wins,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND c2.close_date = close_date) AS Losses,
(SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE c2.close_date = close_date) AS "Avg",
(SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE c2.close_date = close_date) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 WHERE close_date IS NOT NULL GROUP BY close_date
```

This will create table list of trades, but it wont group trades by date because original "close_date" is in form of "2021-09-20 11:11:12.954078 +0000 UTC".

How can I format the close_date so that there is only date (2021-09-20) and use it in joined queries?
I have tried this:

```
SELECT
date(close_date) AS "Date",
.....
```

Which changes the close_date to date as I wanted but then grouping wont work.

I tried to change every close_date to date(close_date) but then the whole syntax breaks.

```
SELECT
date(close_date) AS "Date",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND c2.date(close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Wins,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND c2.date(close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Losses,
(SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE c2.date(close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Avg",
(SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE c2.date(close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 WHERE date(close_date) IS NOT NULL GROUP BY date(close_date)
```

The problem is :

```
c2.date(close_date)
```

How can I format the datetime here ?

c2.close_date (2021-09-20 11:11:12.954078 +0000 UTC) ->
c2.date(close_date) (2021-09-20) ??

Thank you for helping. Im not sql expert in any means so my terminology might be "little bit off".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.

```
SELECT
date(close_date) AS "Date",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Wins,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Losses,
(SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Avg",
(SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 WHERE date(close_date) IS NOT NULL GROUP BY date(close_date)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date using **CAST()** & **CONVERT()** Function

Read more on this function [CONVERT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) & [CAST()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),'2021-09-20 11:11:12.954078 +0000 UTC',105) AS [Date]
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi for answering, but in this case and with my skills I was not able to use your suggestion in any way.

Comment: @user3647376 can you please provide me your table with data?

Comment: sure. here is pastebin link 
https://pastebin.com/c621VFR7

Comment: Thanks for the provide data. Give me some few minutes, I will be back to you soon @user3647376

Answer (score 0):

*Please Refer this code*

```
SELECT
            CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105) AS "Date",
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND CONVERT(varchar(10),c2.close_date,105) = CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105)) AS Wins,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND CONVERT(varchar(10),c2.close_date,105) = CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105)) AS Losses,
            (SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),c2.close_date,105) = CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105)) AS "Avg",
            (SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),c2.close_date,105) = CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105)) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),close_date,105)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. Now the problem is with the varchar and grafana. "no such function: varchar" . I have to figure out somehing.. Of course another solutions are welcome too ;)

Comment: @user3647376  Use "varying(10)" datatype instead of "varchar(10)".

Comment: Thank you for this again, but that wont work on grafana either. :(

Comment: date(closed_date) works perfectly but only problem is when it is used in here:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND c2.date(close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Wins,